# How to get the feedback on Oracle NoSQL Administrative Plans

Tags: oracle-nosql

I am an administrator trying to configure Oracle NoSQL Database; I have submitted an administrative plan from the console and am waiting for some time; however, I am not getting any feedback; how should I check that? Can someone please share some insights on that

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to track the progress of the administrative command.

- The show plan -id  will display the latest status of the command.
- The show topology command will display the current layout of the store, and the NoSQL DB services that currently exist.
- You can issue the verify command to the Admin CLI concurrently as plans are executing. The verify will provide service status information as services come up. You can follow the storewide log via the CLI's log tail command.